# JPA @OneToMany but with only one rekord

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a table in the database that has a @OneToMany link to another table, JPA in standard form will return me the values from the other table as a list, however I would like to get the records as :

> SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id

so if there are 2 records in the table "b" then I should get a list of 2 elements, not a one element list with a list inside that has values from table "b". Additionally, I will point out that I care to implement this by the function "Page findAll(@Nullable Specification spec, Pageable pageable);".
Example entity:

> @Entity
> public class A {
>
> ```
> private Long id;
>
> @OneToMany
> private List<B> b;
> ```

soo i like to look like this

> @Entity
> public class A {
>
> ```
> private Long id;
>
> @OneToOne
> private B b;
> ```

But when theres more that one B i will get second rekord instede of error.

What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: Your annotations are wrong - class A @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b"), class B @ManyToOne

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking for and what you are getting. JPQL will return the mapping, so each A you get will have its complete list of B instances within it by design. If you want only a single B and its associated A, why not query for Bs? "Select b from B b fetch join b.a". Every instance of B will have the associated A populated based on your pagination.